# Getting invalid identifier SQL query

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute next query:

```
MERGE INTO NOTIFICATION_OBJS p
  USING (SELECT 
   :fcsNotif_id as doc_id,
   :OKPD2_code as OKPD2_code,
   :OKPD2_name as OKPD2_name,
   :quantity_value as quantity, 
   :purchaseObject_price as price 
   FROM DUAL
  ) v
  ON (p.doc_id=v.doc_id)
  WHEN  MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
      p.OKPD2_code = v.OKPD2_code,
      p.OKPD2_name = v.OKPD2_name,
      p.quantity_value = v.quantity_value,
      p.price = v.price

  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (p.doc_id, p.OKPD2_code, p.OKPD2_name, p.quantity_value, p.price)
    VALUES(v.doc_id, v.OKPD2_code, v.OKPD2_name, v.quantity_value, v.price)
```

I am sending to bind method next dictionary:

```
{'OKPD2_code': '62.02.30.000', 'OKPD2_name': 'some text', 'purchaseObject_price': '20466982.25', 'quantity_value': '1', 'fcsNotif_id': '18941152'}
```

[image]

But I am getting error:

```
ORA-00904: "P"."OKPD2_NAME": invalid identifier
```

All other query with binding are working. Please help me to find error.

Comment: please Show ddl of `NOTIFICATION_OBJS`

Comment: Use `"OKPD2_name"` instead of `OKPD2_name` https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `OKPD2_NAME` column in `NOTIFICATION_OBJS`  table.

If you used double quotes while creating that table (and its columns), you should

- recreate the table without double quotes, or
- reference the table (and its columns that use mixed case) using double quotes again, specifying case EXACTLY as it was while creating the table

**[EDIT, after the screenshot has been uploaded]**

Column name really is created using mixed case, so you'll have to reference it exactly like that: `"OKPD2_name"` paying attention to double quotes and mixed case.

If you use `"okpd2_name"` or `"okPD2_NAME"` or anything but `"OKPD2_name"`, it won't work. Once again: get rid of double quotes.

Comment: As I told you: you have to use double quotes, i.e. `"OKPD2_name"`